# Setup OCSP stapling - verify CA certs

Tags: nginx, ssl, certificates

I'm trying to setup OCSP stapling on two hosts using nginx

Both certs have different issuers: **Rapidssl** and **Thawte**

Which one is the right one for [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com/roots/)?

Which one is the right one for [Rapidssl](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=INFO1548)?

And last.. How can I verify them with each host cert?

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /var/ini/ssl/ca-bundle/thawte-ca-certs.pem  /var/ini/ssl/domain.com/public.crt
```

And when running the openssl command.. Which cert do I have to verify with? The public cert, the intermediate cert or the bundled with both the public and intermediate cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consider which intermediate certificate(s) you need to exec command:

```
openssl x509 -in a.pem -text -noout|grep Issuer:
```

where `a.pem` is your certificate.

Then you must get all the intermediate and root certificates. You can make them in one file or put them in directory.

In the command you exec above

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile thawte-ca-certs.pem  public.crt
```

you should have in `thawte-ca-certs.pem` root and other intermediate certificates to check the validity of `public.crt`